# The requirement for the element $g^a$ to belong to $\langle g^{p^{e-1}}\rangle$ when $|\langle g\rangle|=p^e$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ as a cyclic group of order $n=p^e$ where $p$ is a prime number.
The generator $g$ satisfy $g^{p^e}=1\bmod p^e$. Thus, the order of cyclic group $\langle g^{p^{e-1}}\rangle$ is $p$.　According to the wikipedia of Pohlig-Hellman algorithm ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm&gettingStartedReturn=true)), $h_k=(g^{-x_k} h)^{p^{e-1}-k} \in \langle g^{p^{e-1}}\rangle$ because the order of $h_k$ divides $p$. However, I cannot understand this statement. The order of any element of $G$ must divide $p$ simply because the order of $G$ is $p^e$. Some elements belong to $\langle g^{p^{e-1}}\rangle$ and the other doesn't belong to $\langle g^{p^{e-1}}\rangle$ because the order of $\langle g^{p^{e-1}}\rangle$ and $G$ is different. So, what does this statement mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that "The order of any element of G must divide $p$ ...". But all we actually know is that the order of any element of G must divide $p^e$.

The statement in the Wiki article therefore requires you to prove that the order of $h_k$ is only $1$ or $p$.